# Экспорт функций lib файла подключенного в dll файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, lib

У меня есть **lib** файл, в котором содержится несколько функций и класс. Он подключается в **dll** файл, который в свою очередь используется программой.

Есть ли какой-то способ получить функции, объявленные в **lib** файле через **dll**?

По типу `__declspec(dllexport) FunctionFromLibFile`

Comment: Ну если они с external linkage, то __declspec(dllexport) FunctionFromLibFile как раз сработает

Comment: Если я правильно понял, я добавил в код строку ```__declspec(dllexport) FunctionFromLibFile``` скомпилировать не получается. Если попытаться указать тип возвращаемого значения, то компилятор указывает на повторное объявление функции